# .ipa file could not installed in an any IOS

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-ios

I am building hybrid app by using react-native . I have got android app is perfectly but I have tried to build .ipa file in an IOS then it's getting an error like "app is could not installed "

I have archived file in xcode but and I got one folder inside apps folder is there inside the folder there is a .ipa file and I have connected ipod to IMAC. I have sent to that file through itunes but not installed just it's showing installing but it could not install.

Please any can help me out I have been trying to solve this problem for several days

Thanks

Comment: does you app build & run on Xcode on iOS devices?

Comment: can you share proper error message or a  screen shot.

Comment: Yes
How Can I share you exactly an error ?

Comment: xcreenshot the error and aslo put code which u r trying

Comment: Thanks @AkshayMulgavkar
I got it it was solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add UUID into your provisioning profile.

steps:

1. go to https://developer.apple.com/account/
2. go to `Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles` menu
3. Open `iPhone` in `Device` in the sidebar and add your device UUID. (if you don't know you UUID then click [here](http://whatsmyudid.com/) to get it)
4. open `Provisioning Profiles`in the sidebar.
5. Select your `iOS Provisioning Profiles` and Edit.
6. Select device in Devices section to add to Provisioning Profiles.
7. Generate and download again